# Sistema de login dando erro!

Tags: php, mysqli

Estou tentando fazer um sistema de login, fiz o form para que quando o botão fosse pressionado ele enviasse pra uma página com o seguinte código:

```
<body>
    <?php
      $conexao = mysqli_connect("localhost", "123456", "senha","banco")
    ?>
    <?php 
    // RECEBENDO OS DADOS PREENCHIDOS DO FORMULÁRIO 
    $email  = $_POST ["email"];
    $senha  = $_POST ["senha"];

    mysqli_query($conexao, "SELECT * FROM voluntarios WHERE email = '$email' and senha = '$senha'");
            if (email = '$email' & senha = '$senha') {
                header("Location: indexVol.php");
            } else {
                echo "E-mail e/ou senha errados!";
            }
        }
    ?>


</body>
```

Porém ao colocar os dados e dar o submit, aparece essa mensagem de erro no Chrome: arthur.000webhostapp.com não consegue atender a esta solicitação no momento.

Alguém tem alguma ideia do porquê? Tem algo errado no código?
Desde já agradeço.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Teu código está com muitos erros, primeiro está faltando um `;` e no final:

```
$conexao = mysqli_connect("localhost", "....", "....","....")
```

Faça assim:

```
$conexao = mysqli_connect("localhost", "....", "....","....");
```

E este teu if está totalmente errado:

```
if (email = '$email' & senha = '$senha') {
```

Não é assim que se usa if && || e etc, fora que mysqli_query não retorna dados, ele executa apenas, o que retorna dados é `fetch`

> Na verdade essa if nem é necessário, a checagem já esta no `SELECT`

E no final do teu código tem um `}` sobrando:

```
    }
?>
```

O header provavelmente não vai funcionar:

```
header("Location: indexVol.php");
```

Porque header tem que vir antes de qualquer conteudo, ele é parte do cabeçalho HTTP, você pode troca-lo por javascript que funciona no front-end ou usar `ob_start`, no caso como é um redirecionamento simples JavaScript deve resolver.

Recomendo também que sempre **faça a checagem** das execuções e conexões:

```
<?php
//$link é a variavel da "conexão"
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* Verifica erros de conexão */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit;
}

$email  = $_POST ["email"];
$senha  = $_POST ["senha"];

// o or die verifica erros na query
$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM voluntarios WHERE email = '$email' and senha = '$senha'") or die(mysqli_error($link));


/* array associativa */
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
    echo '<script>window.location="indexVol.php";</script>'; //Redireciona
}

/* libera a memoria */
mysqli_free_result($result);

/* fecha a conexão */
mysqli_close($link);
```

E aprenda o básico de lógica da programação (já que teu if não tinha sentido) e de ifs no php e também aprenda o básico do mysqli (api do PHP pra conectar no mysql)